# How can I return the number of stock sold and bought without defaultdict?

Tags: python, dictionary

For this problem, we are given this dictionary whose keys are names; which has tuples with 3 values: in the 3-tuple, a stock name, number of shares traded for that transaction (int), and price of each share (int).

```
new_dict = {
    'Carl': [('Intel', 30, 40), ('Dell' , 20, 50), ('Intel',-10, 60), 
('Apple', 20, 55)],
    'Barb': [('Intel', 20, 40), ('Intel',-10, 45), ('IBM',   40, 30), 
('Intel',-10, 35)],
    'Alan': [('Intel', 20, 10), ('Dell',  10, 50), ('Apple', 80, 80), ('Dell', 

-10, 55)],
    'Dawn': [('Apple', 40, 80), ('Apple' ,40, 85), ('Apple',-40, 90)]
  }
```

I am creating a traded function that takes in new_dict and returns a dictionary where keys are all the stocks that appear in transactions; the value is a stock is a 2-list where the first index is the number of shares of that stock bought and whose second index is the number of shares of that stock sold. **Bought** is positive stock and **sold** is any stock with a negative number.

The output of this function should be:

```
{'Intel': [70, 30], 'Dell': [30, 10], 'Apple': [180, 40], 'IBM': [40, 0]}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
def traded(database :{str: (str, int, int)}) ->dict:
    result_dict = dict()
    intel = []
    dell = []
    apple = []
    ibm = []



    for key, val in database.items():
        pos_sum = 0
        for x in val:
            if x[1] > 0:
               pos_sum += x[1]

    return pos_sum
```

I am trying to do this for each stock company individually by having separate lists for each stock company, but I feel that is just tedious. I'm not sure what other techniques there are to do this for each stock company individually.

Is there a simple, easy to understand way to do this, preferably without `defaultdict`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you (although there is certainly a more compact way) :

```
stock_dict = {}
for user_list in new_dict.values():
    for stock_tuple in user_list:
        stock_name = stock_tuple[0]
        if (not (stock_name in stock_dict.keys())):
            stock_dict[stock_name] = list(stock_tuple[1:])
        else:
            stock_dict[stock_name][0] += stock_tuple[1]
            stock_dict[stock_name][1] -= stock_tuple[2]
```

- You could also zip and sum, but its less intuitive.

Basically what you do is create a value for the specific key (if it doesn't exist - this part is only necessary because you dont want to use a default dict), and if it does exist you add the relevant values.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `defaultdict` you can use `dict.setdefault`:

```
d = {}

for k, v in new_dict.items():
    for company, shares, price in v:
        if shares > 0:
            d.setdefault(company, [0, 0])[0] += shares
        else:
            d.setdefault(company, [0, 0])[1] -= shares
```

**Result**

```
{'Apple': [180, 40], 'Dell': [30, 10], 'IBM': [40, 0], 'Intel': [70, 30]}
```

**Explanation**

- Set default value for dictionary items to `[0, 0]`.
- Then we can iterate `new_dict` and increment shares at the appropriate index.
- For shares *sold* we must negate in order to extract a positive result.

---

**defaultdict solution**

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: [0, 0])

for k, v in new_dict.items():
    for company, shares, price in v:
        if shares > 0:
            d[company][0] += shares
        else:
            d[company][1] -= shares
```

Comment: is there a simpler way to do it using defaultdict or regular dict?

Comment: @generation_coding, The above method *is* a regular `dict`. `collections.defaultdict` has similar logic bus is internally more efficient.

Comment: how can i alter that solution to use defaultdict?

Comment: @generation_coding, Added. Please accept (green tick on left) if this solves your problem.